# Disable placeholder border in Sitecore page editor mode

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, page-editor

I'm using Sitecore CMS placeholders for inserting controls into our layout.

```
<sc:Placeholder ID="plhContentPage" Key="content-page" runat="server"  />
```

But when page is in edit mode it leads to borders outside of this placeholders (see screenshot).

[image]

This leads to various artifacts related to our page.

Is there a way to disable this border in page editor mode, because they are not useful for our users.

Comment: I hoped to find it in webedit.css, but it's not there. Seems like it's hard-coded in Sitecore's page editor javascripts somewhere..

Answer (score 2):

You need to un-tick the 'Controls' tickbox in the 'View' tab of the page editor.

[image: example screenshot]

If you need to edit the CSS styles that the page editor uses then you can look at the `webedit.css` which should be located in the root of your website.

Comment: I need to completely disable this border for placeholder (even when Controls is checked) Is it possible?